# How to render objects in hyperHTML

Tags: javascript-objects, hyperhtml

I've been asked to create a dropdown menu using hyperHTML for an exercise. I'm new to this framework and admittedly haven't found a great deal of material on hyperHTML online, but I've drafted a basic template based on what I've read. The problem is when I attempt to run my script using JSFiddle, it returns nothing from the entire div contents. Is anybody able to explain why this might be?

```
// HTML

<div id="drop"></div>

// JS

const modes = [{label: 'Driving', value: 'driving'},{label: 'Walking', value: 'walking'},{label: 'Cycling', value: 'cycling'}];

const render = hyperHTML.bind(document.getElementById('drop'));

render`
  <h1>Hello, world</h1>
  <select>
    ${modes.map(obj => wire(obj)`<option value="${obj.value}">${obj.label}</option>`)};
  </select>
`;
```

Note: It is only when I add the code within the select parameters that JSFiddle refuses to render the div contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see from your code, you should have an error about the undefined `wire`, as you don't reference it anywhere.

This is the code I've used in [this code pen](https://codepen.io/WebReflection/pen/dybLGYo?editors=0010), and everything works just fine.

```js
const modes = [
  {label: 'Driving', value: 'driving'},
  {label: 'Walking', value: 'walking'},
  {label: 'Cycling', value: 'cycling'}
];

const {bind, wire} = hyperHTML;
const render = bind(document.getElementById('drop'));

render`
  <h1>Hello, world</h1>
  <select>
    ${modes.map(obj => wire(obj)`<option value=${obj.value}>${obj.label}</option>`)};
  </select>
`;
```